# CSS table affect on another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-tables

I have this CSS table code:

```
 .navgroups table#rightTable {
     float: right;
     width: 33%;
 }
 .navgroups table#leftTable {
     float: left;
     width: 33%;
 }
 .nvagroups td#centerTable {
     margin: auto;
 }
```

In the middle table I want to insert an image, but the problem is bigger then just 33% (image size).
Every single letter in the middle table lowers the left table from the bar.

I tried the `display:inline` and `display:inline-block`.

Comment: can you add your html too?

Comment: Any reason there tables? Why not use `div`s?

Comment: Also, why is your `#centerTable` a `td`?

Comment: I dont understand what you saying. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cx48u/) Thats what you said right?

Comment: HTML: http://jsbin.com/AKaPEjEg/1/edit
Ruddy, I'm trying to do what you did but the image will be in the same height.

Comment: I will try to write my problem clearer: I have 3 tables in my website and in the middle-table I inserted an image. But then it lowers the content of the left table by a line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just put this as an answer and I don't think anyone can get much better then this with the information you provided.

### HTML:

```
<table class="rightTable">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="leftTable">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="centerTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.greeningaustralia.org.au/images/global/gallery-image.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
.rightTable {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
}
.leftTable {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.centerTable {
    margin: auto;
    width: 33%;
}
table {
    outline: 1px solid;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is 3 tables all `33.33%` with an image that fits in the center one.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cx48u/)

And in this demo below we have text in the other tables. Works fine.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cx48u/1/)

---

### Update:

Demo of using 1 table instead of 3.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cx48u/4/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for help!
Your code helped me, but there's one more question - how can I fit the image to the tables' height?

Thanks again!

Comment: You want to give the `table` a height and then set the `img` height to `100%`. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cx48u/2/)

Comment: Could you explain me what you did there?
Sorry for my ignorance, I don't know what's nth-child..

Comment: Dont worry about `nth-child` its just a way to select a child of a parent. Here, enjoy this: [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cx48u/6/) - There are no need for tables for this. So use lists, then `display: inline;`.

Comment: I like to use tables but it seems that lists are more comfortable.
I will use lists now.
I am appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Another thing Ruddy, 
the distance from left menu to its edge is different from the distance from the right menu to its edge.
What can I do?
DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/UNuWamo/2

Comment: You need to start learning this better. Its the padding. Setting it to 0 will fix it. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsbin.com/UNuWamo/3/)

Comment: I changed the padding in the right menu instead the left menu. I use in UTF8 then it made some problems.
I do need to relearn. Tnx.

Comment: @rolory It works in there, should I be getting paid for this? So much help and you cant even accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry. have a nice weekend

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea. Something like this:

```
<style>
  table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px #cccccc solid; /* for cells preview */
  }
  td.left, td.right {
    width: 33.33%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;  /* for cells preview */
  }
  td {
    border: 1px #cccccc solid; /* for cells preview */
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  td.middle {
    text-align: center;
  }
  td.middle img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">
      Left cell content
    </td>
    <td class="middle">
      <img src="http://themify.me/demo/themes/pinshop/files/2012/12/man-in-suit2.jpg">
    </td>
    <td class="right">
      Right cell content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, so much! 
But another problem woke up:
http://jsfiddle.net/z9LRG/
This is my current menu.
Now, go to "td" in CSS and delete the border.
The image disappears. WHY?